# How to solve the error "The name :1.83 was not provided by any .service files" (PCManFM-Qt Version at Debian 11 bullseye)

Tags: debian, ssh, pcmanfm

When I try to connect to a remote server using PCManFM-Qt Version: 0.16.0:
"Go" "Connet to server" "Type SSH" I get the error message:
The name: 1.83 was not provided by any service files

Does did not solve to install: jmtpfs mtp-tools libmtp-runtime cdtool libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libtiff5 umtp-responder go-mtpfs gmtp libid3tag0 lxqt-archiver libfm-tools nautilus. Strangely nautilus connects without any errors.

Interestingly, the connections I make in Nautilus show up in PCManFM-Qt

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo killall gvfsd
nautilus -q
```

No need to reboot anything. Just plug again and open Nautilus.